# r copy a folder with subfolders in it

Tags: r, directory, move

Is there a command to copy a folder including all its subfolders with files to other directory? I dont want to create the new directories and then using copy.file to move the files, Id like to make it faster.

```
location_folder ="path1"
new_location = ="path2"
name_folder="folder"
```

Comment: [`?file.copy`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/files) informs @joran's suggestion.

Comment: #joran if you mean something like:
    dir1 <- paste0(path1,"folder")
    dir2 <- paste0(path2,"folder")
    file.copy(dir1,dir2,recursive=TRUE)
it doesnt work, i get an error

Comment: #joran, you were right, now it works